# Zscaler Firewall allowing access on a specific embedded Youtube video

Tags: youtube-api, firewall, zscaler

I have a problem on the website of one of our client and I don't know if this problem can be solved.

Currently we embedded some Youtube video on website page of our client example:

The problem is that my client use `Zscaler Firewall` and had blocked Youtube for all his network so videos can't be visible on the page of their website in their network.

They wanted to add just some video on white list to allow them to be watch.

But I found out that the embedded link is not allowed and (ex: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ir7J0eEuWgk) is not enough because Youtube generated a temporary link for each video on `href:blob` attribute.

Is it possible on some way to call the API with a fixed link ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [Stack Exchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/allow-embedded-videos-while-keeping-youtube-blocked):

> It is not possible to allow embedded video while keeping the corporate
>   firewall unless you change the configuration in the proxy server. The
>   easiest way is to convert the Youtube video to a more readable format,
>   store locally on your hosting server and embed in your webpage 
>   tag.

Here some [alternatives to the video block videos with `<video>` tag](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/174523/alternatives-to-the-video-block-embedding-reactive.html).